# wordpress comment form in blog page

Tags: wordpress, post, comments, blogs

I am trying to develop a [wordpress site](http://constantin-entertainment.info/job123) , My blog page shows all the news from my site. Can I fix recent comments with comment form  in all posts displaying in blog page. If I just click on the read more button, content with recent comments and comment form want to show. is it possible?? I am trying with

```
 <?php comment_form(); ?>
```

in my template, but it shows only comment form, if we are write any comment means it redirect to single news page.

Comment: can u check with Settings->discussion(left side menu)->Allow people to post comments on new articles (ticked)->save

Comment: already done, no use